# Youtube playing extremly slowly in Firefox on OpenSuse TW

Tags: opensuse, firefox, youtube

I installed a fresh OpenSuse TW system on my beautiful machine, and everything went flawlessly, except for YouTube.

I installed the damn codecs with `opi codecs`; I enabled/disabled hardware acceleration and enabled/disabled `media.hardware-video-decoding.force-enabled`; I enabled/disabled `layers.acceleration.force-enabled`; I enabled/disabled `gfx.webrender.all`; None of these solutions worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, YouTube by default enables this damn feature called `Ambient Mode`, which slows down everything! For the folks out there, when you play a video, open the settings and uncheck the Ambient Mode.

Further, here is my current configuration for my AMD (integrated graphics) system:

- `media.hardware-video-decoding.force-enabled` **enabled**
- `hardware acceleration` **disabled**
- `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` **disabled**
- `gfx.webrender.all` **enabled**
- `opi codecs` installed ([docs](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Installing_codecs_from_Packman_repositories))